# Yii Multisubmit relation model only one submit button

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have relationship table:

Table `root_cause`:

- id_root_cause
- root_cause

Table `capa`:

- id_capa
- id_root_cause (FK_tbl_root_cause)
- capa
- timeline, ect

And this is  example form layout:

[image]

The scenario is, the `capa` table adds using the `add_capa` button with a modal, with `id_root_cause`, but that doesn't have `id_root_cause` before.

How can I use the save button after inputting multiple data of type `capa` has finished?

Comment: You can put received data for "capa table" in session otherwise you will return it to view filling input hidden field related to capa table rows just inserted.

Comment: thank you for your respon @FabrizioCaldarelli if i use tbGridview, how i can set dataprovider to session ???

Comment: I have tried to clean up the formatting and the English as much as possible - you don't have to specifically add `<br>` tags in Markup.